How to remove/clear previous inline suggestion in monaco editor?
I am providing inline suggestion to the monaco editor in react app which is working properly using the following code:
monaco.languages.registerInlineCompletionsProvider("plaintext", {
  provideInlineCompletions: async function (model, position, context, token) {
    console.log('provideInlineCompletions', model, position, context, token);
    return Promise.resolve({
      items: [
        {
          "label": "",
          "sortText": "a",
          "insertText": autoCompleteAssetDesc.desc,
        }
      ]
    })
  },
  freeInlineCompletions(completions) {
    console.log('freeInlineCompletions', completions);
  }
});

Every time the above code is executed a new inline suggestion is added to the stack of suggestions, and all the suggestion can be accessed by using the toolbar that appears on hovering on the grayed out suggestion as shown in the following screenshot, or by using keyboard shortcuts:

In the above case the latest suggestion is in the 17th place in the stack, and the 1st one, which is also visible as the grayed out text is the oldest one.
I would like to clear the suggestion stack so that there is only one suggestion in the stack every time the above code is executed to add a new suggestion. I looked into the monaco editor docs, and also on stackoverflow, but, couldn't find anything.
It would be great if someone could point my in the right direction or provide a code snippet or example to accomplish above task. Let me know if more info is needed from my end.
Thanks in advance.
